# Given two dense disjoint subsests their interior is empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to prove the following statement: Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and let $A, B$ be two disjoint dense subsets of $E.$ Then $\mathring A=\mathring B=\emptyset.$

By definition, $\overline A=E=\overline B.$ Also, $\overline A= \mathring A \,  \cup \partial A.$ Thus, $\emptyset=E^c=(\mathring A \,  \cup \partial A)^c=(\mathring A)^c \, \cap (\partial A)^c.$ For the boundary $\partial A$ one could eventually write $\partial A=\overline A \,\cap (A)^c. $ But this does not bring me further. I suspect that I should somehow connect $A$ and $B$ and the fact that they are disjoint. Also $E$ is not only a set but a metric space.

Can somebody help me figure out the solution. Many thanks.

Comment: The equation $\partial A=\overline A\cap A^{\complement}$ is not valid. The equation implies that elements of $\partial A$ cannot be elements of $A$, but that is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathring A$.

Then set $\mathring A$ is open and not empty so that $\mathring A\cap B\neq\varnothing$ because $B$ is dense.

(Further explaining: observe that ${\left(\mathring A\right)}^{\complement}$  is closed, so if $\mathring A\cap B=\varnothing$ or equivalently $B\subseteq{\left(\mathring A\right)}^{\complement}$ then $\overline B\subseteq{\left(\mathring A\right)}^{\complement}$ so that $x\notin \overline B$, contradicting that $B$ is dense.)

Then also $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$ because $\mathring A\subseteq A$ contradiction that the sets $A$ and $B$ are given to be disjoint.

We conclude that $\mathring A$ must be empty and on a similar way we also find that $\mathring B$ must be empty.

Comment: Thanks. How you got from $B\subseteq{\left(\mathring A\right)}^{\complement}$ to $\overline B\subseteq{\left(\mathring A\right)}^{\complement}
$ ? Is the relation I wrote above true or false, $ \emptyset=E^c=(\mathring A \,  \cup \partial A)^c=(\mathring A)^c \, \cap (\partial A)^c $? If it were true then we must have $(\partial A)^c=\emptyset,$ which does not seem to hold. Do you agree ?

Comment: If $U$ is open then $U^{\complement}$ is closed. So if in that case $B\subseteq U^{\complement}$ then $\overline B\subseteq U^{\complement}$. Here $U=\mathring A$ and $\mathring A$ open by definition. The equalities in your comment are correct, and indeed lead to $(\partial A)^{\complement}=\varnothing$ or equivalently $\partial A=E$. Why do you think that this does not hold?

Comment: Many thanks. The reason is: $\partial A=\overline A \,\cap (A)^c.
$ So that from $(\partial A)^c=\emptyset$ it follows that: $\emptyset=(\overline A)^c \, \cup A=\emptyset \, \cup A=A.$ Do you agree ?

Comment: I do not agree, because the equality $\partial A=\overline A\cap A^{\complement}$ is not valid. See my comment on your question. Example: $A=\mathbb Q\subseteq\mathbb R$. Then $\partial Q=\mathbb R$ which is not a subset of $\mathbb Q^{\complement}$.

Comment: Thanks; You are right. It should be: $\partial A=\overline A \,\cap \overline {A^c}.$ It then follows: $\emptyset=\emptyset \, \cup (\overline{A^c})^c$.
Since $(\overline{A^c})=( \mathring A)^c$, it follows that $\emptyset=\mathring A.$ This will then be another proof of the statement I was looking for. Do you now agree ?

Comment: @user249018 but where is it used in this "proof" that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint? If that is not used then it cannot be valid. Example: $\mathbb R$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ but the interior of $\mathbb R$ is not empty.

Comment: It is not used. You are right. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^{0}$ is non empty it must intersect $B$ because $B$ is dense. But then $B$ intersects $A$ which is a contradiction. So $A^{0}$ is empty. Similarly $B^{0}$ is empty.

Comment: I dont understand the first sentence, why a non empty $\mathring A$ must intersect $B$ if $B$ dense ? We know that $\mathring A \subset A$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset.$

Comment: @user249018 if the intersection is empty then the closure of $B$ will be a subset of the complement of the interior of $A$ so will - if this interior is not empty - not be the whole space (as it should because $B$ is dense).